# How to model the impact of x on y but only through the effect of x on z

Tags: simultaneity

I need some help in modelling a relationship.

I have three main variables; Firm risk, firm liquidity and firm diversification.

First, I performed regression analysis and found that firm liquidity has a positive and significant impact on firm diversification.

I have reason to believe that firm liquidity also has an impact on firm risk, but only through its effect on firm diversification.

How do I model and test this relationship? I first thought that including an interaction term between firm liquidity and firm diversification would be a solution, but according to my understanding, the interaction term only says that the impact of firm liquidity on firm risk depends on the level of firm diversification (it doesn't imply that the effect of liquidity on risk is only through the effect of liquidity on diversification.)

Would instrumental variable regression be an appropriate analysis technique?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your dependent variable? Is it firm diversification? _diversification = f(risk, liquidity)_?

Comment: risk = f( liquiidty (through its effect on diversification) ) i.e. liquidity affects risk only through its effect on diversification

Comment: You can use pair-correlation analysis to see if there is any linear correlation between liquidity and diversification. If you are familiar with python, you can use seaborn.pairplot() to do bivariate analysis visually.

If you are looking for an equation to represent risk=f(x,y), you may need to use symbolic regression.